# Theme the landing page after saving new content

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type **Testimonials** and like any other type, it gets displayed after you save it. Is it possible to theme that page into something that says **Your Testimonial has been saved!** instead of displaying the data? I only need this for this specific content type.

**EDIT**: @googletorp
Am I doing this correctly? I placed this code in my custom module *enchance.module* (activated) but I'm still getting the same page: the full version of the published testimonial instead of being redirected to `<front>`.

```
function enchance_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //dpm($form);
    if ($form_id == 'edit-testimonials-node-form') {
        $form['#submit'][] = 'testimonials_redirect_success';
    }
}

function testimonials_redirect_success(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Use the drupal_set_message solution.
  drupal_set_message(t('Your Testimonial has been saved!'));
  // Redirect to custom page solution
  $form_state['redirect'] = '<front>';
}

// I'm not being redirected to <front>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `hook_form_alter` you could for the form for the node type add a submit handler that will redirect to a custom page. Alternatively you could use `drupal_set_message`.

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'the form id for the node form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit_handler';
  }
}

function my_custom_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Use the drupal_set_message solution.
  drupal_set_message(t('Your Testimonial has been saved!'));
  // Redirect to custom page solution
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'url/to/page';
}
```

Comment: +1 Of course you can also combine those two methods, for instance, you can redirect to the front page and have your drupal_set_message show up there.

Comment: Wow, amazing! I'll try it out.

Comment: Stupid question but how do I use the code you just posted?

Comment: @enchance You put it in a custom module, rename the functions so that 'module' is replaced with the name of the module and enter the actual name of the form_id.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are using the wrong form ID. The form ID is normally the name of the function that build the form; it cannot contain characters that a function name cannot contain, such as hyphens.

With Drupal 7, you can implement [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7), and your code would become similar to the following one:

```
function enchance_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#node']->type == 'custom') { // Replace 'custom' with the content type ID.
    $form['#submit'][] = 'enhance_redirect_success';
  }
}

function enhance_redirect_success(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Your Testimonial has been saved!'));
  $form_state['redirect'] = '<front>';
}
```

Taking the assumption that the submission handler was implemented in enhance.module, I used `enhance_redirect_success()`, as the function of a module needs to be prefixed by the module name, with the exception of "private" functions that are prefixed by an underscore and the module name, and the theme functions that are prefixed by "theme_" and the module name.
If there is a module that implements `testimonials_redirect_success()`, and you want to use that function, then you replace "enhance_redirect_success" with "testimonials_redirect_success."